# How to lift a binary function to a quotient?

Tags: lean4, quotient

Kia ora :)

I am trying to use [Quot.](https://lean-lang.org/theorem_proving_in_lean4/axioms_and_computation.html#quotients) in Lean4 to define the integers as the quotient of the Cartesian product of two copies of the natural numbers (type Peano) under the relation:

```
def rel (x y : Peano × Peano) : Prop :=
  (fst x) + (snd y) = (fst y) + (snd x)
```

I have proved that this is an equivalence relation. Furthermore I have shown that the following binary operation on pairs of natural numbers:

```
def sum (x y : Peano × Peano) : Peano × Peano :=
  ((fst x) + (fst y), (snd x) + (snd y))

instance : Add (Peano × Peano) where
  add := sum
```

lifts to the quotient by proving the following theorem:

```
theorem sum_lifts (a b c d : Peano × Peano) : (rel a b) ∧ (rel c d) →  rel (a+c) (b+d) :=
  by << PROOF OMITTED >>>
```

I then make the following definition of the integers. But Lean is unhappy with the way I define `sum_int` on the integers.

```
def ℤ := Quot rel

def sum_int (a b : ℤ) : ℤ := Quot.lift sum sum_lifts

instance : Add ℤ where
  add := Quot.lift sum sum_lifts
```

I see the code in TPIL4 only describes how to lift unary functions to the quotient. How can it be altered for binary functions?

Thanks for the help!

*Side question: is it usual to say something lifts to the quotient? I normally hear people saying this-or-that descends to the quotient. **Am I upside down?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are encountering two challenges related to the fact that the interface for `Quot` in base Lean is rather weak:

- `Quot.lift` is not intended to directly create a function `f : Quot r -> Quot r`.  It is intended to create a function `f : Quot r -> A` for some type `A` where `A` need not be a quotient type.  So your congruence lemma `sum_lifts` is not of the right form to use `Quot.lift`.  It needs to end in an equality, not an equivalence.
- `Quot.lift` is for functions of one argument.  Expanding it to two arguments requires a bit of type-theoretic gymnastics.

There are four ways to do this depending if you are want to use Mathlib and if you want to use Quot or Quotient.

But all of them follow the following approach:

- Find the library function which gives you what you need.
- Work backwards, providing the inputs you need of the correct types.

#### Boilerplate

All my examples will use this variation of your code.

```
import Mathlib.Data.Quot  -- only need for methods 2 and 4

def Peano := Nat
instance : Add Peano where
  add := fun x y => Nat.add (x : Nat) (y : Nat)

-- Instead of Peano × Peano, we will use a custom structure, but it doesn't matter
structure PreInt where
  fst : Nat
  snd : Nat

def PreInt.rel (x y : PreInt) : Prop :=
  x.fst + y.snd = x.fst + y.snd

def PreInt.sum (x y : PreInt) : PreInt :=
  PreInt.mk (x.fst + y.snd) (x.snd + y.fst)

theorem PreInt.sum_congr (a b c d : PreInt) : rel a b → rel c d → rel (sum a c) (sum b d) :=
  by sorry
```

#### Method 1.  Use [`Quot.lift`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Init/Prelude.html#Quot.lift) in base Lean

If you just want to use base Lean, you can use `Quot` to define the space:

```
def Int₁ := Quot PreInt.rel
```

and then use `Quot.lift` to make the function.

Before getting to a function of two arguments, let's do a function of one argument (negation) as an example.  Most importantly, our lift lemma needs an equality at the end, not an equivalence, so we need to work with an intermediate function which goes from `PreInt` to `Int₁`.

```
def PreInt.neg (a : PreInt) : PreInt := PreInt.mk a.snd a.fst
theorem PreInt.neg_congr (a b : PreInt) : rel a b → rel (neg a) (neg b) :=
  by sorry

-- as an intermediate need function from `PreInt` to `Int₁`
def Int₁.negAux (a : PreInt) : Int₁ := Quot.mk PreInt.rel (PreInt.neg a)

-- lift lemma uses equality, not the relation `PreInt.rel`
theorem Int₁.negAux_lifts (a b: PreInt) : PreInt.rel a b → negAux a = negAux b := by
   intro h
   -- use Quot.sound to reduce to congruence property
   apply Quot.sound
   apply PreInt.neg_congr
   apply h

def Int₁.neg (a : Int₁) : Int₁ := Quot.lift negAux negAux_lifts a
```

For two arguments, it is the same idea, but we need two intermediate functions, one of type `PreInt -> PreInt -> Int₁`, and the other of type `PreInt -> Int₁ -> Int₁`:

```
def Int₁.sumAux (a b : PreInt) : Int₁ := Quot.mk PreInt.rel (PreInt.sum a b)

theorem Int₁.sumAux_lifts (a b₁ b₂: PreInt) : PreInt.rel b₁ b₂ → sumAux a b₁ = sumAux a b₂ := by
   intro h
   apply Quot.sound
   apply PreInt.sum_congr
   . rfl
   . apply h

def Int₁.sumAux' (a : PreInt) : Int₁ -> Int₁ := Quot.lift (sumAux a) (Int₁.sumAux_lifts a)

theorem Int₁.sumAux'_lifts (a₁ a₂ : PreInt) : PreInt.rel a₁ a₂ → sumAux' a₁ = sumAux' a₂ := by
  intro h
  -- function extensionality to make it sumAux' a₁ b = sumAux' a₂ b
  apply funext
  intro b
  -- Quot.ind is like cases/induction where we replace a quotient with its inner parts
  apply Quot.ind _ b
  intro b'
  apply Quot.sound
  apply PreInt.sum_congr
  . apply h
  . rfl

def Int₁.sum (a : Int₁) : Int₁ → Int₁ := Quot.lift Int₁.sumAux' Int₁.sumAux'_lifts a
```

#### Method 2: Use [`Quot.map₂`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Mathlib/Data/Quot.html#Quot.map%E2%82%82) in Mathlib

The above gymnastics are just boilerplate, and it is easy to replace `Quot.lift` it with a custom operator designed specifically for building a function which maps two quotient spaces into a third quotient space.  This is what `Quot.map₂` does.

```
theorem PreInt.sum_congr_right (a : PreInt) (b₁ b₂: PreInt) : rel b₁ b₂ → rel (sum a b₁) (sum a b₂) := by
  apply PreInt.sum_congr
  rfl

theorem PreInt.sum_congr_left (a₁ a₂: PreInt) (b : PreInt) : rel a₁ a₂ → rel (sum a₁ b) (sum a₂ b) := by
  intro h
  apply PreInt.sum_congr
  . apply h
  . rfl
  
def Int₁.sum' (a b : Int₁ ) : Int₁ :=
  Quot.map₂ PreInt.sum PreInt.sum_congr_right PreInt.sum_congr_left a b
```

#### Method 3: Use [`Quotient.lift₂`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Init/Core.html#Quotient.lift%E2%82%82) in base Lean

`Quotient` is like `Quot` except it requires that the relation is an equivalence relation.  Also, it works on `Setoid` types, which is just a fancy name for a type with an equivalence relation.

```
theorem PreInt.rel_is_equiv : Equivalence rel :=
  by sorry  -- supply proof here

instance PreInt.preIntSetoid : Setoid (PreInt) where
  r     := rel
  iseqv := rel_is_equiv

def Int₂ := Quotient (PreInt.preIntSetoid)
```

Then Quotient has `lift₂` for functions of two arguments so that helps with some of the boilerplate (but since this is still lift, we have to still make an auxiliary function).

```
def Int₂.sumAux (a b : PreInt) : Int₂ := Quotient.mk' (PreInt.sum a b)

theorem Int₂.sumAux_lifts (a b c d : PreInt) : a ≈ c -> b ≈ d -> Int₂.sumAux a b = Int₂.sumAux c d := by
  intro h1 h2
  apply Quotient.sound
  apply PreInt.sum_congr
  . apply h1
  . apply h2

def Int₂.sum (a b : Int₂) : Int₂ := Quotient.lift₂ Int₂.sumAux Int₂.sumAux_lifts a b
```

#### Method 4.  Use [`Quotient.map₂'`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Mathlib/Data/Quot.html#Quotient.map%E2%82%82%27) in Mathlib

This is similar to `Quot.map₂` but with a slightly different interface.  The theorem you need to prove looks complicated, but it is just using fancy symbols for simple concepts.

```
theorem PreInt.sum_congr' : (Setoid.r ⇒ Setoid.r ⇒ Setoid.r) PreInt.sum PreInt.sum := by
  -- remove the fancy LiftFun notation and then follow your nose
  rw [Relator.LiftFun]
  intro a b h1
  rw [Relator.LiftFun]
  intro a1 b1 h2
  apply PreInt.sum_congr
  . apply h1
  . apply h2

def Int₂.sum' (a b : Int₂) : Int₂ := Quotient.map₂' PreInt.sum PreInt.sum_congr' a b
```

Comment: Amazing answer :) Am I correct in thinking that Method 1  is done by currying and partial application? Quot only lifts functions of one variable so you have to break sum up into two steps? So there needs to be one more step to write a "proper" binary sum on the quotient?

Comment: @user0112358 yes, currying and partial application  are used in method 1.